# Redirection HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following files. The objective of this is to redirect to the correct news. For example:
localhost/tostadotv/esto-es-una-noticia-28.html

If I intentionally modify the url, for example:
localhost/tostadotv/esto-es-una-noticia-modificada-incorrecta-28.html

I should redirect myself to the correct news:
localhost/tostadotv/esto-es-una-noticia-28.html

However, it redirects me to this:
http://localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/localhost/tostadotv/esto-es-una-noticia-28.html

Where this error? Could you please help me thanks. Excuse my english I'm from Argentina I do not speak English

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*-([0-9]+)\.html$ noticia.php?id_not=$1 [L]
```

noticia.php

```
<?php require_once("lib/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("lib/functions.php"); ?>
<?php
fix_category_product_url();
?>
```

functions.php

```
function fix_category_product_url() {      
    $proper_url = get_proper_category_product_url(1);

    if ( SITE_DOMAIN.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $proper_url) { 
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); 
        header('Location: '.$proper_url);
        exit();         
    }
}
function get_proper_category_product_url($id) {   
    $product_id = $_GET['id_not'];

    $query = sprintf('SELECT titulo FROM noticias WHERE id_not = "%d"', mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['DB'], $product_id));
    $restit = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['DB'], $query);
    $noticia = mysqli_fetch_array($restit);

    $proper_url = make_category_product_url($noticia['titulo'], $product_id, $id);

    return $proper_url;
}
define('SITE_DOMAIN', 'localhost');
function _prepare_url_text($string) {    
    $NOT_acceptable_characters_regex = '#[^-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]#';
    $string = iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$string);
    $string = preg_replace($NOT_acceptable_characters_regex, '', $string);

    $string = trim($string); 

    $string = preg_replace('#[-_ ]+#', '-', $string); 

    return $string;
}

function make_category_product_url($product_name, $product_id, $ido) { 
    $clean_product_name = _prepare_url_text($product_name);

    if ($ido == 0)
        $url = strtolower($clean_product_name).'-'.$product_id.'.html'; 
    else 
        $url = SITE_DOMAIN.'/tostadotv/'.strtolower($clean_product_name).'-'.$product_id.'.html'; 

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: If you're uncomfortable speaking English, there is a StackOverflow community in Spanish where many Argentines answer. What is the if-else in `make_category_product_url()` for? What difference does it make? For some weird reason, although not sure, I believe that the `else` block is causing your issue... but I'm not sure, I haven't tested it. I mean, `$ido` is always `1` if I understand it well. En serio, preguntá en español sin drama en la otra comunidad.

Comment: But why is it repeated so many times if there is not a for or a loop? In Stack Overflow in Spanish, they almost never respond. Also post the problem at www.forosdelweb.com

Comment: Well, `header('Location: /path/')` will take you to `/path/` in your site, if it exists. Since `localhost/whatever` can be interpreted as a path (because it doesn't have `http://` or `https://`), then it's most likely redirecting many times, adding that value repeatedly... but I am shocked at the fact that it did find an ending point (or it reached the maximum allowed redirections).

Comment: Then again, I'm not sure, I'm basing that on the fact that you're trying to redirect and on the pattern it's taking... I find it weird it doesn't break on the first or second redirection but, whatever the case may be, it's worth noting and trying.

Comment: YES ZEKE only with this was it solved define('SITE_DOMAIN', 'http://localhost'); http: // was the problem thank you very much

Comment: Wait, what? So it's solved or not? Also, there's no need to yell (that's what you're actually conveying when using uppercase characters).

Comment: Oh, okay, there I see your edit. You're welcome, but I'm confused... what did you end up doing to solve it? Because `define('SITE_DOMAIN', 'localhost');` doesn't seem to solve anything...

Comment: `define('SITE_DOMAIN', 'localhost');` change `define('SITE_DOMAIN', 'http://localhost');`

Comment: Alright, that makes more sense now. It isn't exactly what I was suggesting, but works nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, the final solution for the asker was to add `http://` to the defined `SITE_DOMAIN` constant.

**Before**

```
define('SITE_DOMAIN', 'localhost');
```

**After**

```
define('SITE_DOMAIN', 'http://localhost');
```

But there's more to it than just that. Let's focus on the following two functions:

```
function fix_category_product_url(){      
    $proper_url = get_proper_category_product_url(1);
    if(SITE_DOMAIN.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $proper_url){ 
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); 
        header('Location: '.$proper_url);
        exit();         
    }
}

function make_category_product_url($product_name, $product_id, $ido) { 
    $clean_product_name = _prepare_url_text($product_name);
    if($ido == 0)
        $url = strtolower($clean_product_name).'-'.$product_id.'.html'; 
    else 
        $url = SITE_DOMAIN.'/tostadotv/'.strtolower($clean_product_name).'-'.$product_id.'.html'; 
    return $url;
}
```

The idea here is that `$proper_url` actually ends up getting a value from `make_category_product_url()` because its result is returned by `get_proper_category_product_url()`. It makes sense because `make_category_product_url()` has more parameters and uses the other to get their values.

What's funny about this is that the `else` block of the second function doesn't always return a path, but rather a URL. The problem here is that such URL is given without a defined protocol, but starts with the domain name instead. This value is therefore mistaken as a path.

Now take a look at the first function: it ultimately redirects the user using `header('Location: '.$proper_url);`. As we discussed earlier, `$proper_url` **is not always a path**, so the protocol should be added somewhere in the code whenever a URL takes place instead of a path. That's where the actual solution comes in: adding `http://` where `SITE_DOMAIN` is defined is one way to do this, because this constant is only used when a URL takes place. *There are many other ways to do this*, but this one is completely valid.

Comment: In this great book is the code http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Search-Engine-Optimization-with-PHP-A-Developer-s-Guide-to-SEO.productCd-0470100923.html

Comment: Good. I just decided I would post an answer explaining the reason why the solution is valid. You can accept it or not, that’s up to you. But it’s good to close questions that are already answered. You see, I’m not complaining about the code (although I should because it’s wide open to injections), but rather providing a useful analysis of the problem.